# Iso triangle solution: all (x,y)'s are known, but only apex B identified. Identify which coordinates are A and C

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

You have an isosceles triangle with points labelled ABC

[image]
([source](https://images.tutorvista.com/cms/images/155/isosceles-triangle.png))

"standing" vertically, so B is the apex at the top. Now some rotation then translation in the plane is applied, after which A,B,C are now at the locations A',B',C' respectively. You know the coordinate pairs of A',B',C' and which one of those is B', but you don't know yet which is A' and which is C'.

Figure out which of the two remaining coordinates is A' and C', purely in terms of coordinates, with trig level math, if possible.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but this is for a computer program so a solution must exclude visual observation.

Thank you to the folks at freenode.net #math for helping me to formulate my question into the proper terms. A lead on an answer was given that I might investigate Matrix Rotation:

[image]

That math is beyond the length of my sleeve at the moment, but I'm betting that this might be able to be solved with easier math?

One thought I had was that the slopes a and c will always be negative and positive in relation to a median line from B to the mid point of A and C but, the only way I know to calculate slope is in relation to the coordinate axis’s.

Many Thanks in advance for help with my quandary.

Comment: so in the initial position $AC$ is parallel to axis $x$?

Comment: The initial position does not matter nor does any calculation to derive it's transformation from the initial point. Only which point is A and C matter. The initial location was mentioned as a vehicle to describe the triangle and it's points, specifically that point B is the "top."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tool to distinguish orientation is the planar cross product, defined for two vectors as
$$(a,b)×(c,d)=ad-bc$$
This is also the magnitude of the true cross product of $(a,b,0)$ and $(c,d,0)$, hence the name. It distinguishes orientation in that rotating the two vectors does not change the product, but reflecting the vectors across any line through the origin inverts its sign.

With all points being considered as position vectors, let $n=(A-B)×(C-B)$. Now let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be the two points which are $A'$ and $C'$ but in unknown order; compute $(P_1-B')×(P_2-B')$. If this has the same sign as $n$, $P_1=A'$ and $P_3=C'$; otherwise it is the other way round. No matrices are required at all, and this works for *any* triangle in *any* orientation, as long as only rotations and translations are applied.

Comment: @DanielSevelt Would you like to upvote and accept my answer? (You are new here, I can tell. The upvote button is above the number 0 to the left of my answer; the accept button is a tick below that 0, which will turn green when you click it, marking it as accepted.)

Comment: Of course! 

FYI: Apparently I am *so* new that my upvotes don't matter yet but "will contribute to your reputation," so my upvote doesn't add to your answers displayed upvotes. Apparently someone else with enough reputation will have to vote it up for it to reflect.

Comment: I'm having a last little bit of trouble with subtracting the vectors to arrive at a signed scalar. Is this a correct formula for n?

n=(Ax*Bx-Ay*By) x (Cx*Bx-Cy*By)

I can't find a definitive answer for how to handle this but once I know how to do it correctly the solution is approachable for me.

Comment: @DanielSevelt No, $n=(A_x-B_x)(C_y-B_y)-(A_y-B_y)(C_x-B_x)$.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DanielSevelt Also, I think you can upvote my answer now.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

I'm at 13. :( So close! When I do cross the threshold I will come back and do so. Perhaps they will register automatically when I cross, but I will be sure to make it happen either way.

Comment: @DanielSevelt Try and ask another good question you have. ;)

Comment: Certainly! You're the best!  Now that I've had some time with your solution, it occurs to me you answered this question, but I didn't ask *quite* the right one, but a very similar one: how do I arrive at this conclusion with out knowing the original A B C but only A' B' C'? Same parameters in that the coordinates of all points are known and B' is the apex. 

Is this best asked in another question or is here appropriate?

Comment: @DanielSevelt Another question.

Comment: Ok sure, but the exact same title applies only the description changes.

Comment: @DanielSevelt You should modify the title slightly. No two questions on this site should have the same title.